# display and edit plot x and y axis using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

if a have two big sets of data, and I want to display it using subplots

instead of having [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csCyo.png)

how can I have a better look?  like display y 0,30,60,90. and x 0,20,40,60,80,100

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(LIST1, LIST2)

ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y'      title='chart')
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Try this `plt.xticks(np.arange(0,101,20))` and `plt.yticks(np.arange(0,101,30))`

Comment: it still displays the numbers from the list for x and y. How can I customize the numbers like 30,60,90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the snippet with sample data.

You were displaying `strings` in the plot and hence you were receiving such an output. I converted your result to `float` and see the first image, `matplotlib` itself handles the xlimit and ylimit.

Without using `xticks()` and `yticks()`
[image: Graph1]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
lists1= ['12.0', '15.0', '16.2', '16.3', '16.9', '17.5', '18.6', '19.3', '19.4', '20.2', '21.3', '22.9', '23.5', '25.2', '28.5', '30.5', '31.8', '42.5', '43.3', '45.1', '47.8', '60.4', '63.7', '65.8', '67.8', '69.9', '73.1', '76.4', '79.8', '97.8', '99.2', '100.2', '103.3', '103.6', '110.8', '111.2', '101.2', '103.0', '110.1', '112.3', '123.9']
list1=[float(i) for i in lists1]
lists2 =[ '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017']
list2=[int(i) for i in lists2]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(list2,list1)
ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y',title='chart')
plt.show()
```

After using `xticks()` as you require year gap of 10
[image: Graph2]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=[15,35,24,46,45]
y=[25,53,64,35,75]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y',title='chart')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1970,2030,10))
plt.show()
```

Comment: my list is really big, and it has many floats numbers. I tried this way,  but Y shows 15.7,  and 55.8 some numbers like this.  is there a way that the graph to show some int like 20,40,60?

Comment: @GuangzheYang can you please show both your list? atleast some part of it

Comment: list1= ['12.0', '15.0', '16.2', '16.3', '16.9', '17.5', '18.6', '19.3', '19.4', '20.2', '21.3', '22.9', '23.5', '25.2', '28.5', '30.5', '31.8', '42.5', '43.3', '45.1', '47.8', '60.4', '63.7', '65.8', '67.8', '69.9', '73.1', '76.4', '79.8',  '97.8', '99.2', '100.2', '103.3', '103.6', '110.8', '111.2', '101.2', '103.0', '110.1', '112.3', '123.9']

Comment: list2 =[ '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011','2012,'2013','2014','2015','2016','2017']

Comment: @GuangzheYang why is your numbers in string format in list 1?

Comment: my goal is to display every 10 year and 20,40,60,80,100,120,140

Comment: it works. thanks a lot.  The main reason is my list is str, not int or float?